# 2001 Jeep Grand Cherokee Laredo Value

Tags: jeep, grand-cherokee

I think this is a useful enough question, so I'm posing it. Some kid rear ended me, and it's going to cost more to repair the bumper and two package than my WJ is worth. Can I expect his insurance company to just cut me a check, or do I have to buy my own car back from them? It's perfectly drivable, should I have to go through all of this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot depends on the insurance company and where you live. I have had it go both ways. In one case they offered a check, but wanted the vehicle. In another case they paid me and were happy I didn't make them tow it away.

Be aware that laws vary from state to state and it may be a hassle to reregister the vehicle as it will have a salvage title. This may require reinspection by a DMV officer. It may not pass without the repairs. You may get them to issue you a check without totaling the Jeep by making the payment a little less than the value. That way you have a clean title.

Answer (score 0):

Take the oportunity to put an aftermarket bumper on it at the insurance companies expense.

Somthing like http://www.kevinsoffroad.com/cart/wj-grand-cherokee-rear-bumper-wo-tire-carrier-p-827/

It's cheaper, looks good, and is much stronger.

Insurance claims completly paid of my Dodge Ram for me, and I just fixed everything with aftermarket parts. (My truck has been hit 2 times now, while parked, while I wasnt in it, and someone broke into it and stole my radio). Tubing bumpers, stero system, dash, etc...

I have an 01 WJ also, and I love it.

Comment: I can't charge them for repairs if it's totaled.

Comment: true, but just like mikes said, but they will pay it out and will be willing to work with you. You know you can put a pretty trick bumper and tow package on for less then $1000, so you got the estimate, tell the insurance company you will settle for less in order to avoid the salvage title. And tell them you will fix it yourself so they just cut you a check. They will do anything to pay you less, so if you give them the option they will take it.